# Catch duplicate key exception and continue to insert

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have the table in PostgreSQL with many records and unique key

```
CREATE TABLE parcels
(
    Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Number CITEXT NOT NULL,
    UserId INT REFERENCES Stations(Id) NOT NULL,
    TimeStampUtc TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON parcels (Number, UserId, (TimeStampUtc::date));
```

then I import data from Excel and map it to list. At the end I have something like

```
 await _dbContext.Parcels.AddRangeAsync(parcels);
 await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

`parcels` contains about 20,000 records and can contains records witch violates the unique constraint. In such case I need to skip that records and continue to insert.

Now I got an expected error

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   Npgsql.PostgresException: 23505: duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "parcels_number_userid_timestamputc_idx"

How to ignore it and continue to insert?

I found some similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113418/ignore-duplicate-key-insert-with-entity-framework) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324151/ignore-duplicate-entries-and-commit-successful-ones-on-dbcontext-savechanges-i?rq=1) but I don't want to load table to memory, because there are a lot of records to compare

Comment: Hi, Did you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do is the following:

1. create a stored procedure that receives the parcels and does an insert paired with a join on the column with the unique key constraint (= filter out all that already have a value in the `where` condition)
2. call the stored procedure from your code and pass the parcels

in case you need an artificial id, there are two ways to do it:

- return the ID from the insert function (`returning id`) that the database created automatically for you
- generate the Id on your client (usually only works well when you have GUID columns)